# When compressing a powder from a single direction, does it compress evenly?

Tags: material-science

I have some powder in a container with one side open. If I then compress it from that open side, does the powder evenly compress, or will the side closer to the opening (or furthest from the opening) compress more, and end up with a gradient of compression? For example, when tamping ground coffee in an espresso portafilter - is the coffee density even distributed through the portafilter, or will it be denser at the top or bottom?

And what factors (if any) affect this? Regarding individual particles - shape? size? texture? uniformity? compressibility (of each particle)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to another site https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Consider the forces acting on a given granule in the direction parallel to the compression force. In the pushing direction, there's a term for the piston force minus any dissipative forces acting in between the pushing and the particle.

Comment: In the anti-pushing direction, there's a term for the inertia of the mass farther from the piston that the granule is pushing on, added to a term for all the dissipative forces, added to a term for the inertia of the container (and whatever the container is attached to, like a person or the planet) if the container has to be closed on the end to keep the particles from spilling out. How does each term vary with the position of the particle and the amount to which the powder has already been compressed, vs when it was very loose and free to accelerate?